# Find the coefficient of $x^6$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-distribution

[image]

I can not understand how to solve it .

Can anybody provide me a hint .

***Added:*** There solution is also given but I could not understand it .

[image: solution]

Comment: What is the source?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee it came in my test

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I have provided the solution , may be this is useful

Comment: Please try avoid pictures of text or formula and replace them with typeset mathematics. You can learn about the binomial theorem. It explains which coefficients each term of $(a+b)^n$ gets.

Answer (score 2):

Try multiplying out some terms and ignoring those where the exponent is too big.  For example you could start with

$(1+x)(1+2x^2+x^4)(1+3x^3+3x^6+\cdots)(1+4x^4+\cdots)(1+5x^5+\cdots)(1+6x^6+\cdots)$

Comment: Was doing the same, but I expect something better exists.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: [OEIS A026007](http://oeis.org/A026007) does not suggest to me a simple shortcut

Answer (score 0):

HINT

Multipliers over 6 does not change coefficient of $x^6$